# reweigh cost function in regression

Tags: regression, loss-functions

In fraud detection, we can increase the cost of classification mistakes on the minority class, called cost-sensitive training. penalize-SVM is one of algorithms doing it.

I am wondering if there are similar ways for regression problem? i.e. re-weigh cost by errors:

$C = \sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 \to  C^{\prime} = \sum_i \beta_i(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2$,

where $\beta_i = f(y_i-\hat{y}_i)$ is a function of errors, and here I want to optimize $C^{\prime}$. I feel `adaboost regression` could be an option, but didn't figure out how to implement it in sklearn.

Comment: Yeah you can do a weighted least squares to achieve what you want.  Also sounds like an iteratively reweighted least squares scheme to me. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares

Comment: @Tylerr, great to hear your answer. Thank you. Are there open source like sklearn to deal with this? or we have to work on code on our own? Thanks again